# Installed Datatype from Pod not fully Recognized Swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift-protocols

I installed the Layer api using cocoapods: https://developer.layer.com/docs/ios

However, one of the protocols does not seem to be recognized correctly by my app. I say that for a few reasons. One, in the demo app I have 'LYRClientDelegate' and 'LYRClient' appear green in the dowloadable demo app(https://github.com/kwkhaw/quick-start-ios-swift) and blue in my app. Second I'm having a couple typing errors in my project that I don't see in the demo app even though the code is the same. Third in my app 'LYRClientDelegate' doesn't show anything in Quick Help, but it does show something in the downloaded demo app. But, when I go to jump to declaration in my app, it goes to the same file as the demo app.

Demo app:
[image]

My app:
[image]
My errors:
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show us your Podfile

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong Layer version.

You should try either to fix the code (preferable) or to revert to a previous version.

To revert to a previous version, you can specify it your Podfile

See the reference https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html

My guess is that you should use the version 0.20.x instead of the newly released 0.21... Try to see the one that works for you.

Also, check out this project: https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-iOS

It could save you lot of time prototyping, and can even be used for highly customized apps. See https://itunes.apple.com/app/id997402753

Comment: It's an objective-c pod, so I have '#import <LayerKit/LayerKit.h>' in my bridging header, which is how it appears in the demo app

Comment: I know, and I use this pod too.  With a swift project too.
You don't need to use #import <LayerKit/LayerKit.h> in your bridging header. 
Did you put "use_frameworks!" in your Podfile ?

Comment: So adding import LayerKit worked, but didn't get rid of my errors and when I put use_frameworks! I got 200+ errors all of a sudden. A lot of them were various "Property has a previous declaration" errors

Comment: Hmm did you removed the import once you did it ? And rebuild from scratch after clean/removing derived data ?

Comment: I did remove the import and I removed derived data. I still have those same 5 errors

Comment: Can you show the line which is producing the error ?

Comment: Errors shown above in question. My theory is if it recognizes LRClient properly, it would work

Comment: Which version of layer kit do you use ? They changed many APIs lately and the example projects or older projects might not work anymore

Comment: O that would make a lot of sense actually. I used the one that was on the site 3 days ago. How would I check the exact version?